# log out session button infile

Tags: php, session, button, logout

What is the cleanest and shortest way to LOG OUT from this session?

I would like to create a hyperlinked text when you are logged in this php.

```
<?php 

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 20 < time()) {
        session_destroy(); 
    }
}

else {
    $_SESSION['pass']="" ;  $_SESSION['timeout']=time();
}


if (isset($_POST["pass"])) {
    $_SESSION['pass']=  $_POST['pass'] ; 
}


if($_SESSION['pass'] == 'password') {
    echo 'session';
}

else {
    echo    '<form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="password" name="pass">
            </form>';
}

?>
```

Other solutions suggest creating a "logout.php" file but I would like to do it in the same file.

Thanks XXX

Comment: *"but I would like to do it in the same file."* - so... ok. Just add the href in the same file, and inside the conditional(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you logged in show log out link:

```
if($_SESSION['pass'] == 'password') {
   echo "<a href=\"index.php?logout=true\">logout</a>";
}
```

and then check for logout:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
   session_destroy();
```

Comment: well, it is impossible for me to find something as easy as this this in google so I guess this post will become important for ignorants THANKS Mikhi XXX